# Excel: read text as string instead of regex

Tags: excel

I'm somewhat new to excel and right now working on a sheet that simply counts the sales numbers of products.

I'm using the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('salesreport'!$A$1:$A$1048576,'SalesNumbers'!$A1)
```

The salesreport sheet contains the data with product names in the A column, the SalesNumbers sheet contains a List of the product names in the A column and the mentioned formula in the second column.

Now to the Problem, some of the products have different variants and a * on the name ending e.g. "Product A*", "Product A large*".
Since the * is interpreted as any following text by Excel, the counter for "Product A*" will include the large variant.

Since I receive the data from outside its difficult to simply get rid of the * for future reports which should just be copy/pasted into the template.

The easy way to solve the problem is obviously to subtract the count of the large variant. The Problem I have with that is, that the formula is no longer consistent for all products and might cause problems if somebody beside me will work on the template.

Is there any way to make Excel read the name in the A column as a string instead of a regex?

Thank you in advance!

Ascani0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly then you can use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(salesreport!$A:$A=SalesNumbers!$A1))`

**Edit 2** SUMPRODUCT is powerful and pretty useful ARRAY formula which finds many usages. Here we use it to do specific COUNTIF like stuff.

- *salesreport!$A:$A=SalesNumbers!$A1* part tests equality
- It generates boolean ARRAY of {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE....FALSE}
- This result cannot be directly passed on to SUMPRODUCT which expects numeric data. So to achieve numeric coercion, we apply double unary (--) which can be also achieved by using +0 or *1 etc methods.

**Edit** And if you want to use COUNTIFS then you can use it like below:

`=COUNTIFS(salesreport!$A:$A,SUBSTITUTE(SalesNumbers!$A1,"*","~*"))`

Here tilde(~) does the work as escape character and allows checking of asterisk (*) in literal sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hello @Ascani0, you can read about SUMPRODUCT a lot on Web. I'd suggest you to read the subforum on vbaexpress especially the sticky posts written by Bob Philips aka xld. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?98-SUMPRODUCT-And-Other-Array-Functions